# How can I add numbers to a single variable between defined functions? [Python]

Tags: python

First of all I'm complete beginner. Currently trying to write a simple game using only functions and if-else statements. Basically, I defined some functions and in each function there's a question and corresponding answers. The player will gain points according to the answer. The answer that he gave will lead the player to another function (question) and he/she will also gain points from there. After completing all of these questions, I need to sum all points to say if the player failed or not. I did a search about how to count those points and came up with "global" variables but I failed how to implement them on my program. Besides point count, everything works well. Thanks for the help and sorry for my English.

Comment: Sharing sample code showing just where you're going astray  may help people help you.

Comment: You could define a global list to keep track of each player's score: `scores = [0 for _ in range(number_of_players)]`. Then in each question function update the score for the current player: `scores[current_player_number] += <point value for a right answer>` each time a right answer is given. Doing it this way would sum the points up as they are acquired so you won't need to sum anything at the end.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, just a simple example.  On StackOverflow you're **always** supposed to show what you've tried so far; if you've tried nothing, then you'll get no help.

Answer (score 1):

As you say your a beginner, I would recommend you to take an easier approach than a global variable. Pass the current sum of points to each function with questions. Then in each function add the new points to the sum, if the answse is correct and return the new sum of points.

```
def question1(points):
    "Ask question"
    If(user_answer==correct_answer):
        points = points + points_gained
    return points

Sum = 0
Sum = sum + question1(sum)
Sum = sum + question2(sum)
```

Continue as showed above, this should work out and is quite simple.

Hope it helps!

Etc.